# Is the biomass decreasing?

Tags: ecology, general-biology

Is the overall biomass decreasing over time, and if yes, has that trend started within the last say $200$ years (about when industrialization started)?

**EDIT.** Let me add some of my own attempts to answer this question.

**Reasons that the biomass might be decreasing.** Humans have such a big impact on the environment that the current era is called the [Anthropocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropocene). Species are disappearing in masses. We put a lot of artificial chemical substances like pesticides and herbicides into the ground. All this makes it plausible that the overall biomass is decreasing. However...

**Reasons that the biomass might be increasing.** Humans are big animals, bigger than most species (and host to many bacteria). Their number has [increased sharply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_growth) in the last $200$ years. The $\text{CO}_2$ that humans output might lead to increased plant growth, and the higher temperatures might make macroscopic life possible in areas with little life.

**Bottom line.** It might be the case that *animal biomass* is increasing (due to human population growth), but the *total biomass* is decreasing because of the intense deforestation in the Amazon basin and other places.

Comment: What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your hints - will do this!

Comment: @theforestecologist I chose to edit the answer, can you re-open it? Or is it preferable that I create a new thread?

Comment: Don't focus too much on land-based biomass. The impact of climate change and ocean acidification on plankton causes probably much larger changes of total biomass on earth than anything else.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Net Ecosystem Production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_ecosystem_production). Biodiversity seems positively related to NEP as e.g. concluded [here](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2020.2063). As we are causing the [sixth mass extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene_extinction) ceteris paribus the NEP should decline. Other factors that changed over the last centuries may increase NEP e.g. monocultural plantations [can yield higher productivity](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0709069104) in abundant resource environments.

Comment: Now as long as NEP is positive, I would expect the biomass defined as the mass of all living organisms to increase.